# How can I tell the current price I'm paying for a Spot instance with EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using elastic beanstalk and in my `env.yaml`, I have:

```
  aws:ec2:instances:
    InstanceTypes: g4dn.xlarge,c5.4xlarge,r5.2xlarge,r5a.xlarge
    EnableSpot: true
    SpotMaxPrice: "0.15"
    SpotFleetOnDemandBase: "0"
    SpotFleetOnDemandAboveBasePercentage: "0"
```

When I go to my `instance`, I see under `Lifecycle`, that some are `spot`. But how do I know how much I'm paying for it?

Comment: To check the pricing for spot instances, please see the answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31530925/13907163

Comment: Great - please post as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pricing for spot instances is dynamic and billing takes place on an hourly basis. As long as the spot instance price is below the max bid price specified by you, the instances will remain operational and billing will continue.
For more details please check the answer : [How to get the price of a running EC2 spot instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31529353/how-to-get-the-price-of-a-running-ec2-spot-instance/31530925#31530925)